# Show float number on a button

Tags: java, android, floating-point, charsequence

I'm writing an application for Android, and I have difficulties with writing float value on a button as a text. I tried this:

```
float Percentage1 = (Level1/16)*100;
String s = Float.toString(Percentage1);
percent.setText(s+"%");
```

And this:

```
float Percentage1 = (Level1/16)*100f;
percent.setText(Float.toString(Percentage1));
```

It's always show me 0.0% on the button. If anyone has on idea how to do that, please respond!

Comment: In both examples you perform division on int values, which I believe results 0. Try `float Percentage1 = (float)Level1 / 16 * 100;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(Level1/16)` will be computed in *integer arithmetic*; i.e. its remainder will be discarded.

To remedy, use `(Level1/16.0)*100;`. Using `16.0` causes the expression to be evaluated in floating point.

Comment: No problem. But do study *why* it works, and, in particular, why `(Level1/16)*100.0;` doesn't.